# Longtable exeedes page length

Tags: longtable

I have a table which i have made using longtable. but the table will not brake over to the next page, it continues outside the page.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.09in}|p{1in}|p{3in}|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{Produktspesifikasjon}\\
\hline
Navn: & Dato: & Prosjekt: & Skal & Bør\\ \endfirsthead \endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Funksjon: } & &\\ [30pt]
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{1.Funksjonsegenskaper/krav}} & & \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{1.1 Prosess: } & & \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Detektere og slukke brann}
 &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{} && \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{1.2 Produkt:} & &\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Pålitelig} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Minimal skade for maskineri} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Rask reaksjon ved brann} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Effektiv slukking} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{1.3 Ergonomi:} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Uskadelig for mennesker} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{1.4 Betjening:} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Automatisk} &x&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Manuell} &x&\\ [20pt]
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{2.Omgivelser}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{2.1 Rommet:} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Gulvareal =} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Rommets volum =} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem HPU, kompressor, maskinutstyr} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Olje} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Lekablokker} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{3.Utseende}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Skal ikke være til hinder for bruk av rommet} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{4.Prosjektplan}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Design: 5 måneder} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{5.Kostnader}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Utviklingskostnader: ikke spesifisert} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Produksjonskostnader: ikke spesifisert} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{6.Produksjon/montering}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Utføres av godkjent leverandør} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{7.Standarder}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Sprinkler: NS-EN 12845:2015} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Vanntåke: BS-EN 14972} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Gass: NFPA 2001:2018} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Skum: EN 13565} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Inert luft: NFPA 69} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Pulver: EN 12416} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\tabitem Alarmsystem: NS 3960:2013, NS-EN 12094, NS-EN 54} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{8.Sikkerhet}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Sikker mot skade} &&\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{9.Miljø}} &&\\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Lekkasjer og søl} &&\\
\hline 

\end{longtable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Delete the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` statements and recompile.

Comment: (1) welcome, you are using a float around the `longtable`, float cannot break across pages. By its very nature `longtables` does not float. Simple remove the `table` environment around your `longtable`

Comment: Please also tell us how `\tabitem` is defined.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the table environment helped! 
\tabitem is defined as: \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, why folks provide good answers to a question and prefer thus keeping this question as unanswered for ever.

So: Don't nest a longtable inside a float environment. In your case remove the table environment and if there are no other issues, the longtable won't run off the page any more.